# Issue with Terraform accessing list value of a key in YAML file

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, terraform-provider-azure

I am deploying azure service bus using terraform and yaml conf file. I am creating
azure service bus name pace, network rules for the service bus and service authorization rule for the name space using terraform.but,i want to define the multiple topics and multiple subscriptions under the topics in a yaml file which  will be accessed by terraform as parameters during creating the resources "topic" and "subscription". I  have defined the Multiple subscriptions as list value of the topic. The topics are created successfully but the Multiple subscriptions are not. The error , yaml, and terraform conf are given below.

```
 Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on main.tf line 215, in resource "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "subscription":
│  215:   name       = each.value.servicebus_subscription
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value.servicebus_subscription is tuple with 2 elements
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "name": string required.
```

```
con.yaml
#-------
servicebus:
  - servicebus_topic: tesTopic1
    #enable_partitioning: "true"
    servicebus_subscription: ['test-service1', 'test-service1']

  - servicebus_topic: testTopic2
    servicebus_subscription:['test-db1', 'test-service2']
```

`````
pub_sub.tf

resource "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "subscription" {
  for_each = { for subscriptions in local.service_bus_conf : subscriptions.servicebus_topic=> subscriptions}
  depends_on = [azurerm_servicebus_topic.topic]
  name       = each.value.servicebus_subscription
  topic_id   = data.azurerm_servicebus_topic.topic[each.value.servicebus_topic].id

}

````
`````

Comment: Can you please provide the code used to load the yaml file?

Comment: locals {
  service_bus = yamldecode(file("${path.root}/conf/servicebus/svc.yml") ["servicebus"]
}